# How to add correctly a new service provider in L5?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5, composer-php

I've found this page :
https://gist.github.com/rtconner/40b415073378da28b2bf
 where it's shown a Service provider to be added in L5 in order to manage sftp connection driver in filesystem configs. Which is supposed to solve a issue.

Anyway once I executed via console:

```
 php artisan make:provider SftpServiceProvider
```

And edited the SftpServiceProvider class as shown in the above webpage.
I went to config/app.php to add

```
'providers' => [
...
     'App\Providers\SftpServiceProvider',
...
]
```

I tried a

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize (with and without the option)
```

But always I get a error:
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'App\Providers\SftpServiceProvider' not found

In fact, I cannot see in my vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
the line addressing to SftpServiceProvider

Also executing a

```
composer update #will not be ok.
```

Again the errors:
- Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error
- [RuntimeException]  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Providers\SftpServiceProvider' not found

What do I miss in the ServiceProvider creation procedure?

Thanks